# Copy range between two cell values in column A

Tags: excel, vba

I am naive to macros. I would like to copy range in column A between two cells which has specific values. As shown below, I want to copy all data between USA & JAPAN (EXCLUDING BLANK DATA) and paste in another workbook in specific column.
I appreciate your kind help.

```
Column A
==============
0
1

USA
2
13
45
52
46
57
88


11
13

JAPAN
25
27
55
```

I tried below CODE but some error in line Consultant3.Select

```
Sub SelectMyRange()

Dim Consultant1 As Integer, Consultant2 As Integer
Dim Consultant3 As Range
Dim rngFind As Range    

Set rngFind = Columns("A:A").Find(What:="OBJ NO.", After:=Range("A1"), 
LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
SearchDirection:=xlNext)

If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
  Consultant1 = rngFind.Row + 2
End If

Set rngFind = Columns("A:A").Find(What:="OBJ END", After:=Range("A1"), 
LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
SearchDirection:=xlNext)

If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
  Consultant2 = rngFind.Row - 1
End If

If Consultant1 > 0 And Consultant2 > 0 Then
  Set Consultant3 = Range(Cells(Consultant1, 1), Cells(Consultant2, 1))
End If

Consultant3.Select
Selection.Copy

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your problem? Lookup [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-pastespecial-method-excel). With `PasteSpecial` you can skip blanks.

Comment: Please see my updated question and the code I tried.

Comment: Your code is searching "OBJ NO." and "OBJ END". However, in your example I cannot see any cell with those values. Why don't you start replacing "OBJ NO." with "USA" and "OBJ END" with "JAPAN"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, explanation inside the code as comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectMyRange()

Dim Consultant1 As Range, Consultant2 As Range
Dim Consultant3 As Range

' set the Range Cell directly
Set Consultant1 = FindRange(Columns("A:A"), "USA")

' set the Range Cell directly
Set Consultant2 = FindRange(Columns("A:A"), "JAPAN")

If Not Consultant1 Is Nothing And Not Consultant2 Is Nothing Then
    ' just use Offset on Cell's (set as range), and set it to only cells with values inside
    Set Consultant3 = Range(Consultant1.Offset(1, 0), Consultant2.Offset(-1, 0)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
End If
' copy the Range (there's no need to select it first)
Consultant3.Copy

' Paste to "Sheet3" Range "A2" < -- you can modify to your destination
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

End Sub

'======================================================================

Function FindRange(Rng As Range, FindStr As String) As Range

Set FindRange = Rng.Find(What:=FindStr, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

End Function
```

Comment: Dear Rado, If there are multiple sheets it is giving error. Is it possible to refer to particular sheet and copy data from there.